# Assigning a value for each day for the past 2 weeks using 14 buckets to store them

Tags: java, algorithm

This is kind of hard to explain but I need to come up with an algorithm that will use these 14 value buckets to move through it based on the day and assign them to these buckets..

For example, if started today (monday), value would go to bucket #1, for sunday it would be #7, sunday after #14 and the next day, on monday, it would use the #1 bucket again..

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Use simple array or ArrayList and for index use `i % 14`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the days and use modulo:

```
int bucket = (days % 14) + 1
```

If you start at 0; you can leave out the +1.

Calculating the day:

```
long start = ...
long current = System.currentTimeMillis();

int bucket = (int) ( ((start - current) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) % 14 )
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response, but how would I count the days.. I was looking at Calendar class, and there's a method called getTimeInMillis, it would be perfect if i could get that in Days I guess.. Also this calculation will be happening on a mobile device so it needs to efficient.. Thanks